# jQuery ui accordion normal links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using jQuery UI `accordion()`. I have 4 tabs. I want to make 2 sliding which is the way accordion works, and the other 2 just normal links without sliding. I can't figure out how to do normal link since accordion expects an element for content after the `<h3>` tag

```
<div id="test">
    <h3><a href="#">One</a></h3>
    <div>
        some text
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Two</a></h3>
    <div>
        some text
    </div>
    <h3><a href="whatever.html">Link</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="whatever1.html">Link</a></h3>
</div>
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/3JAkv/

Comment: Place your links outside accordion, and apply the same style to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the accordion methods(http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), I don't recognize anything for locking an item unopenable.

Why don't you just take the

```
 <h3><a href="whatever.html">Link</a></h3>
<h3><a href="whatever1.html">Link</a></h3>
```

outside of the `<div id="test">` div and just style them properly?

Also, you could have a different selector for header, which will disable the item. For example: i changed the last two links to h2 and set the accordion to use h3 as header:

```
$('#test').accordion({ header: 'h3' })
```

and

```
<h2><a href="whatever.html">Three</a></h2>
<h2><a href="whatever1.html">Four</a></h2>
```

you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3JAkv/5/

you still have to skin it with CSS though

Answer (score 4):

You can alter the click on the last 2 tabs via `jquery`:

```
$('h3 span').slice(2) // accordion adds a span to put the triangle icon
                      // deactivate the click on it
                      // slice(2) to take last 2 tabs
            .click(function(){
    return false;     // deactivate the click
});

$('h3 a').slice(2).click(function(){
    location.href = $(this).attr('href'); // redirect the page to
                                          // the href of current anchor
    return false;                         // deactivate the click
});
```

#### *jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3JAkv/7/*

Comment: Thanks but it's a little too much code for what i want to do. +1

Comment: thank you for this, it solved my problem exactly. i had a long list with items interspersed that didnt have children. i needed the ones without children to keep their links. AWESOME!!

Answer (score 1):

Took me a couple of days but I finally found an answer.

Build out your accordion as suggested in the documentation with empty divs below your headings that don't have sub entries. Then you need these two functions.

```
//make links work in accordion headers
$("#accordion h3 a").click(function() {
    window.location = "default.html"+$(this).attr('href');
    window.location.reload();
    return false;
});

//cycle through each header, checking if the next div has html and remove ui-icon class if it doesn't
$("#accordion h3").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).next("div").html() == "") {
        $(this).children("span").removeClass("ui-icon");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take the links out of the accordion:

```
<div id="textParent">
    <div id="test">
        <h3><a href="#">One</a></h3>
        <div>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Two</a></h3>
        <div>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="whatever.html">Three</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="whatever1.html">Four</a></h3>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers